# Android app is debuggable on Charles when not supposed to be (Nougat vs Marshmallow)

Tags: android, proxy, android-6.0-marshmallow, charles-proxy, android-7.0-nougat

I want to create two versions of my app:

1. Debuggable by Charles
2. Not debuggable by Charles (to prevent external users from tracing the traffic)

I already know that Nougat behaves differently, and in order to be make Nougat behave like Marshmallow and below I have to add the following xml (which is essentially the default behaviour for Marshmallow and below) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config>
      <trust-anchors>
         <certificates src="system" />
         <certificates src="user" />
      </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and then I have to add the following to the "application" tag in the manifest -

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

My problem begins here: I'm creating two flavors in my app. One with the above xml (which works fine on both versions), and one with the same xml, only `<certificates src="user" />` is removed, which is supposed to **not** be debuggable in Charles, on both versions.

I cannot debug it on Nougat, but for some reason, it is debuggable by Charles on Marshmallow. Why is that? And how can I fix it?

Comment: The network security configuration XML is not used on Android 6.0 and earlier. `user` certificates are always honored on Android 6.0 and earlier, unless you set up your own custom `TrustManager` (e.g., for certificate pinning).

Comment: Also, adding the following `debug-overrides` section to your network_security_config.xml may make it easier to achieve your goal. The section will be honored only in debuggable builds of the app. IDEs usually produce debuggable builds by default, unless you're building a release build.

`
<debug-overrides>
  <certificates src="system"/>
</debug-overrides>`

See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Comment: @AlexKlyubin thank you, that was my first solution :) trouble is, I need it on a release configuration.